# Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Message=Bad JSON escape sequence: \A

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to load the json data from the API source using Azure Data Factory.
I'm getting error below whcih is bad json escape sequence.

```
ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file 'api/vc/report/16277292d17ac20a5d0d073d0f8fa45bf848a89e2e0c9fcebb707f187fcf9cdce88ceb70c'. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Message=Bad JSON escape sequence: \A. Path 'Data[43999].work_order', line 1, position 39435083.,Source=Newtonsoft.Json,'
```

Above error I got when the destination dataset has the encoding of UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

If I set the encoding as UTF-8 in dest DS in ADF. data is loading successfully  to ADLS as json file, but I'm unable to read/parse (tried reading in text and json formats) the json file in databricks/dataflow. getting error like (AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default.....).

Is there any way to replace the invalid escape sequence while reading from source in ADF?
Or Any other solution to handle this situation?

this is the sample data

```
{
    "Report ID": "123",
    "Report Name": "JSON_1",
    "Data as of Date": "2024-01-18 01:28 PM",
    "Report Date": "01/18/2024 08:27 AM",
    "Report Header": "",
    "Report Footer": "",
    "Data": [
        {
            "ID": "01",
            "Supplier": "COMPANY",
            "Type": "Standard",
            "Work_ID": "fg",**"work_order":"T\A Harvey"**,
            "Purchase_Order_Number": "2",
            "Statement_of_Work_Status": "Approved",
            "Primary Cost Object": "3 | BASE",
            "Primary Cost Object Code": "10014",
            "Item": "Limit ",
            "Item_ID": "rg23",
            "Item_Status": "R",
            "S_Worker_ID": "",
            "Worker_ID": "",
            "Worker_Name": "",
            "Master_Number": "",
            "Role_Code": "",
            "Role_Level": "",
            "Invoice_ID": "",
            "Item_Submit_Date": "12/09/2023 12:39 PM"....15 more columns
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Coud you please provide your sample JSON?

Comment: Hi Bhavani, I have added the sample data, which I'm trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below approach using the databricks to replace escape characters before using it as source in ADF

As you mentioned that you can't change the data at the source side.
And have to handle that loaded Json data(UTF-8) and need to replace the escape character, and parse and store as a csv data.

You can follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Load the JSON data into a DataFrame in Azure Databricks.

```
json_data = '''
{
    "Report ID": "123",
    "Report Name": "JSON_1",
    "Data as of Date": "2024-01-18 01:28 PM",
    "Report Date": "01/18/2024 08:27 AM",
    "Report Header": "",
    "Report Footer": "",
    "Data": [
        {
            "ID": "01",
            "Supplier": "COMPANY",
            "Type": "Standard",
            "Work_ID": "fg",
            "work_order": "T\\A Harvey",
            "Purchase_Order_Number": "2",
            "Statement_of_Work_Status": "Approved",
            "Primary Cost Object": "3 | BASE",
            "Primary Cost Object Code": "10014",
            "Item": "Limit ",
            "Item_ID": "rg23",
            "Item_Status": "R",
            "S_Worker_ID": "",
            "Worker_ID": "",
            "Worker_Name": "",
            "Master_Number": "",
            "Role_Code": "",
            "Role_Level": "",
            "Invoice_ID": "",
            "Item_Submit_Date": "12/09/2023 12:39 PM"
        }
    ]
}
'''
```

**Step 2:** Replace the escape characters in the DataFrame.

```
json_data = json_data.replace('\\', '')
schema = StructType([StructField("Report ID", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("Report Name", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("Data as of Date", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("Report Date", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("Report Header", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("Report Footer", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("Data", StringType(), True)])
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json_data]), schema=schema)

file_path = "abfss://folder02@newgenstg.dfs.core.windows.net/exmpl.json"
```

**Step 3:** Write the DataFrame to CSV format and store it in ADLS.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").json(file_path)
```

Results:

```
Report ID   Report Name Data as of Date Report Date Report Header   Report Footer   Data
123 JSON_1  2024-01-18 01:28 PM 01/18/2024 08:27 AM         [{"ID":"01","Supplier":"COMPANY","Type":"Standard","Work_ID":"fg","work_order":"TA Harvey","Purchase_Order_Number":"2","Statement_of_Work_Status":"Approved","Primary Cost Object":"3 | BASE","Primary Cost Object Code":"10014","Item":"Limit ","Item_ID":"rg23","Item_Status":"R","S_Worker_ID":"","Worker_ID":"","Worker_Name":"","Master_Number":"","Role_Code":"","Role_Level":"","Invoice_ID":"","Item_Submit_Date":"12/09/2023 12:39 PM"}]
```

The above code is replacing escape characters from the JSON data. and converting JSON string to dataframe and writing to ADLS.

However, Azure databricks has the capabilty to load json data in  python request package.

The below is the example:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1,name,href')
db1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([resp.text])
df2 = spark.read.json(db1)
```

`requests` module, which allows Python code to send **HTTP** requests and It retrieves data from the **API** endpoint
**Spark RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset)** parallelizing the text

```
spark.read.json
```

reads from the **Spark RDD**

Comment: Hi Dileep, Thank you for the Answer, However, In my case, actually we can't change the data at the source side. I have to handle that loaded Json data(UTF-8) and need to replace the escape character, and parse and store as a csv data.

Comment: Hi @Tharun I have tried again and updated the solution can you check and let me know if it help you?